# Overall GCP Data Statistics

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I am currently preparing for our internal audit evaluation & cleanup for GCP. As the data is in TBs across various services & projects. To start with, is there a way to get service/project/location level data stored in the Google cloud platform linked to the respective billing accounts that includes cloud storage, big query, compute engines (persistent disks) & other services from GCP.

Can we extract these data from audit/billing logs in a simple way or do we need to explore individual services/projects with respective commands like bq, gsutil, gcloud commands?

Currently I am using the following ways to estimate the overall storage across all projects within bigquery & storage:

For Bigquery:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  SUM(bytes)/(1024*1024*1024*1024)
FROM (
  SELECT
    SUM(size_bytes) AS bytes
  FROM
    `<project-x>.<dataset-1>.__TABLES__` union all
  SELECT
    SUM(size_bytes) AS bytes
  FROM
    `<project-y>.<dataset-2>.__TABLES__` union all .....)
```

For Storage:

```
gsutil -o GSUtil:default_project_id=project-id du -shc

#This command executes slower with increasing number of files in the bucket
```

Comment: Have you tried the [billing dashboard](https://medium.com/google-cloud/visualize-gcp-billing-using-bigquery-and-data-studio-d3e695f90c08)? Seems like a ready to use solution, maybe not as granular as you seem to desire, but should be easy enough to extend.

EDIT 1: The dashboard works on [labels](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-labels), so if you don't have them you have to re-architect the solution to suit your use case

Comment: yes, I do have a separate customized report using the billing dashboard template but it focuses more on the project spendings for services, amount of data processed & audit/usage logs

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I believe it could be possible to get an answer from the billing reports through bigquery, but is not quite trivial. From my test project with the export active, I see something like:

_omitted_
Cloud Storage,
Download US EMEA,
2017-10-02 10:00:00,
2017-10-02 11:00:00,
_omitted_,
_omitted_,
0.0,
USD,
1.0,
24656.0,
bytes.

So, you can potentially use anything that has usage.unit == _bytes_ or _bytes-seconds__ to determine the data you have. But you have to do a bit of reverse engineering. Also, keep in mind the free quotas to have a complete picture.

Comment: I do not believe what you are asking exists at this point, please fill up a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)