# how to get the total size of all the datasets available in my project in google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

I am using gcloud version 'Google Cloud SDK 204.0.0' I need to get the total size of all the datasets available in my project and total size of all the tables of datasets in my project (I think total size of dataset will also give me the total size of all table of a datasets.) and total size of all the buckets in my project. I am bound to use cloud SDK version 204.0.0 which is older one. Any idea on how to get these details will also be highly appreciated. Kindly help.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to know this space? especially for bigquery?

Answer (score 1):

Neither of those are possible using the core GCloud SDK. They come as specific components, `bq` and `gsutil`. If you are bound to a specific version due to permissions required to update you won't be able to install these components should you not have them, they are installed by the exact same process as the core update.

You can check if they are installed with `gcloud components list` and, if you are allowed, install them with `gcloud components install bq gsutil`.

Now, assuming you have those components installed, let's proceed. We'll automate a lot of piping from one command to another, so I'll use `jq`. You can take the values manually if you want to.

#### BigQuery

To list datasets we use `bq ls`, quite simple. To get just the names we'll pipe that like this:

`bq ls --format json | jq -r '.[] | .id'`

To list the tables in a dataset we do `bq ls <dataset>`. Piping that into jq we have:

`bq ls --format json <dataset> | jq -r '.[] | .id'`

Combining with the previous line using `xargs` we can list all the tables with:

`bq ls --format json | jq -r '.[] | .id' | xargs -L1 bq ls --format json | jq -r '.[] | .id'`

Lastly, we need to get the size of the tables we use `bq show <table>`. This gives us a lot of unnecessary information, we can reduce what we want into nice objects like this:

`bq show --format json <table> | jq -s 'map({(.id): {"rows": .numRows, "bytes": .numBytes}}) | add'`

Now combining everything:

`bq ls --format json | jq -r '.[] | .id' | xargs -L1 bq ls --format json | jq -r '.[] | .id' | xargs -L1 bq show --format json | jq -s 'map({(.id): {"rows": .numRows, "bytes": .numBytes}}) | add'`

This will give you the answer in this format:

```json
{
  "<project>:<dataset>.<table>" {
    "rows": "47",
    "bytes": "3637"
  },
  ...
  "<project>:<dataset>.<table>": {
    "rows": "449464",
    "bytes": "73899799"
  }
}
```

#### Cloud Storage

This one is easy, just `gsutil du -s` will give you the size of each bucket.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response @Luiz Ferraz
I have got the size of each buckets but I want the size in GB/TB in more readable formats.

Yes I have installed bq and gsutil components, hope this should help me.
I am new to google cloud, could you please help to understand what is 
jq -r , 
jq -s ,
xargs -L1

Thank you

Comment: `jq` is a json manipulation CLI. I highly recommend learning about it as it will help you a lot in doing things from the terminal: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: `xargs -L1` runs a command for every line piped into it, so we get a list of all tables and run a command for each one of them

Comment: You can run each step separately if you are not comfortable with `jq` and `xargs`. To get the readable values for GCS the command is `gsutil du -s -h`. For BQ you'll need to divide the size in bytes by 1024 3 times for GiB or 4 times for TiB or just paste them into Excel/Google sheets and format it as bytes

Comment: not sure if this would help you out (check the sql & gcs command) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52439685/overall-gcp-data-statistics

Comment: 'jq' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
I don't think my banking client will allow me to install any other tools that's not available in their repository.

I have tried below command and first one worked fine but second one didn't.

--For Single Table of a dataset --
bq show dataset_name.table_name

--For All Tables of a dataset--
bq show dataset_name.*